# Converting columns with date in names to separate rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-transform

I already got answer to [this question in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754184/converting-columns-with-date-to-rows-in-r), wondering how this can be implemented in Python.

Let's say we have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'2019Q1':[1], '2019Q2':[2], '2019Q3':[3]})
```

which displays like this:

```
   2019Q1  2019Q2  2019Q3
0       1       2       3
```

How can I transform it to looks like this:

```
Year    Quarter    Value
2019    1          1
2019    2          2
2019    3          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = d.stack().reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={0:'Value'})
df[['Year', 'Quarter']] = df.pop('level_1').str.split('Q', expand=True)
```

```
   Value  Year Quarter
0      1  2019       1
0      2  2019       2
0      3  2019       3
```

---

If you care about the order of columns, use `reindex`:

```
df = df.reindex(['Year', 'Quarter', 'Value'], axis=1)
```

```
   Year Quarter  Value
0  2019       1      1
0  2019       2      2
0  2019       3      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `MultiIndex` with `expand=True` and then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last data cleaning with with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html):

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'2019Q1':[1], '2019Q2':[2], '2019Q3':[3]})

d.columns = d.columns.str.split('Q', expand=True)
df = (d.unstack(0)
       .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
       .rename_axis(('Year','Quarter'))
       .reset_index(name='Value'))
print (df)
   Year Quarter  Value
0  2019       1      1
1  2019       2      2
2  2019       3      3
```

Thank you @Jon Clements for another solution:

```
df = (d.melt()
       .variable
       .str.extract('(?P<Year>\d{4})Q(?P<Quarter>\d)')
       .assign(Value=d.T.values.flatten()))
print (df)
   Year Quarter  Value
0  2019       1      1
1  2019       2      2
2  2019       3      3
```

Alternative with `split`:

```
df = (d.melt()
       .variable
       .str.split('Q', expand=True)
       .rename(columns={0:'Year',1:'Quarter'})
       .assign(Value=d.T.values.flatten()))
print (df)
   Year Quarter  Value
0  2019       1      1
1  2019       2      2
2  2019       3      3
```

Comment: Not entirely sure as it'd need testing, but something like: `df.melt().variable.str.extract(r'(?P<Year>\d{4})Q(?P<Quarter>\d)').assign(Value=df.values.T)` should do the trick...

Comment: Okay... had a quick play with the above, and I reckon: `df.melt().variable.str.extract('(?P<Year>\d{4})Q(?P<Quarter>\d)').assign(Value=df.values.flatten())` should do it :)

Comment: (that way it scales to > 1 row)

Comment: @JonClements - Thank you, also is necessary transpose before flatten - `d = pd.DataFrame({'2019Q1':[1,8], '2019Q2':[2,9], '2019Q3':[3,0]})`