# Converting columns to rows in Pandas with a secondary index value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Following up to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767731/converting-columns-with-date-in-names-to-separate-rows-in-python):

```py
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'value':['a', 'b'],'2019Q1':[1, 5], '2019Q2':[2, 6], '2019Q3':[3, 7]})
```

which displays like this:

```
   value    2019Q1  2019Q2  2019Q3
0  a        1       2       3
1  b        5       6       7
```

How can I transform it into this shape:

```
Year    measure    Quarter    Value
2019    a          1          1
2019    a          2          2
2019    a          3          3
2019    b          1          5
2019    b          2          6
2019    b          3          7
```

Comment: and there can be more years right? like 2020Q1?

Comment: Yes, that should be dynamic

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any leads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns = df.columns.str.split('Q').str[::-1].str.join('_')

new_df = (pd.wide_to_long(df2.rename(columns = {'value':'Measure'}),
                          ['1','2','3'],
                          j="Year",
                          i = 'Measure',
                          sep='_')
            .reset_index()
            .melt(['Measure','Year'],var_name = 'Quarter',value_name = 'Value')
            .loc[:,['Year','Measure','Quarter','Value']]
            .sort_values(['Year','Measure','Quarter']))

print(new_df)
   Year Measure Quarter  Value
0  2019       a       1      1
2  2019       a       2      2
4  2019       a       3      3
1  2019       b       1      5
3  2019       b       2      6
5  2019       b       3      7
```

Comment: Not OP, but that is SO MUCH prettier than what I was working on. Nice solution!

Comment: Nice one @ansev

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ansev. Nice answer

Answer (score 0):

this is just an addition for future visitors : when u [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns and use expand=True, u get a multiindex. This allows reshaping using the [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method.

```
#set value column as index
d = d.set_index('value')

#split columns and convert to multiindex
d.columns = d.columns.str.split('Q',expand=True)

#reshape dataframe
d.stack([0,1]).rename_axis(['measure','year','quarter']).reset_index(name='Value')


  measure   year    quarter Value
0   a       2019       1    1
1   a       2019       2    2
2   a       2019       3    3
3   b       2019       1    5
4   b       2019       2    6
5   b       2019       3    7
```